# Unix How to check if a specific word is entered in as an argument

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm writing a script in Unix but I need a way to check an argument that is entered in the command line is a specific word.

So if when using the script the user types:

```
$ ./script hello
```

my script can tell that "hello" was entered as an argument and can display a message appropriately.

And if the user types something other than "hello" as an argument then my script can display another message.

Thanks.

Comment: `if [ "$1" == "hello" ]; then echo "has hello"; else echo "does not have hello"; fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == hello ]];then
echo "hello was entered"
else
echo "hello wasn't entered"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to check positional arguments against a list. When there are a number of items in the list, you can use a `case` statement instead of a string of `if ... elif ... elif ... fi` comparisons. The syntax is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in

    "hello" )
        printf "you entered hello\n"
        ;;
    "goodbye" )
        printf "well goodbye to you too\n"
        ;;
    * )
        printf "you entered something I don't understand.\n"
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

**Output/Use**

```
$ ./caseex.sh hello
you entered hello

$ ./caseex.sh goodbye
well goodbye to you too

$ ./caseex.sh morning
you entered something I don't understand.
```

Answer (score 2):

In Bash arguments passed to shell scripts are stored in variables named as follows:

```
$0 = name of the script.
$1~$n = arguments.
$# = number of arguments.
$* = single string of all arguments: "arg1,arg2,..."
```

you can simply use `if [ $1 == "some string" ]; then ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the command line arguments with $(number)

for example the first argument would exist at $1 the second at $2 etc.

You can use conditionals in BASH (I assume you are using bash) just like any other language; however the syntax is a bit wonky :). here is a link for you 
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_07.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the position of the argument you can :

`#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == SearchWord]];then
echo "SearchWord was entered"
else
echo "SearchWord wasn't entered"
fi`

Incase you are not sure:

You can use `$*`

```
[ `echo $* | grep $SearchWord| wc -l` -eq 1 ] && echo "Present"|| echo "Not present"
```